# How to get the duplicate sku data from below pattern

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Here's the pattern of arrays. The sku is in vaiants(sub arrays).I want to fetch the data on the basis of sku . If the same sku are in a same(root array) then output should be only that.If the same sku are in different (root arrays) then the output should be both the array data.How to do it dynamically.

```
    $arr = [
    '0' =>[
    "title" => 'first product',
    'prpduct_id'=>23424,
    'variants'=>[
        0=>[
                'variant_id'=>8654,
                'title'=> 'small prouct',
                'sku'=>'pro001'
            ],
        1=>[
                'variant_id'=>6556,
                'title'=>'second small product',
                'sku'=>'pro002'
            ],
        2=>[
                'variant_id'=>63258,
                'title'=>'third small product',
                'sku'=>'pro001'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1=>[
    'title'=>'second product',
    'product_id'=>93255,
    'variants'=>[
        0=>[
                'variant_id'=>63259,
                'title'=>'small box',
                'sku'=>'pro002'
            ],
        1=>[
                'variant_id'=>63259,
                'title'=>'second small box',
                'sku'=>'pro003'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    2=>[
    'title'=>'third product',
    'product_id'=>321456,
    'variants'=>[
        0=>[
                'vaiant_id'=>32695,
                'title'=>'large products',
                'sku'=>'pro003'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Can you fix your array? There is so much wrong with it that I cant make it run!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this code will work but since there is so many errors in your array posted here I can't test it, I can't even find them all.
Misspelled words, dots instead of commas and much more.

This loops the array, echos the product title and then finds all SKU's associated with array_column, and array_unique returns the unique SKU's.
Then I implode the array with new line.

```
foreach($arr as $prod){
    echo $prod['title'] . " SKU's:\n";
    $sku = array_intersect_key($prod['variants'], array_unique(array_column($prod['variants'], 'sku')));
    // $sku is now the array data of the unique SKU's.
    // Echo them how you want, for demo purpose I use var_dump
    Var_dump($sku);
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Edit finally fixed all your errors, here is a running version of the code: https://3v4l.org/CBnoL

Comment: Thanks for your help!!. But I want the whole data (everything related to that sku).

Comment: Yes, @Andreas I have seen the update.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Currently  I am trying to fetch the same sku whole data together.  Means first two data with same sku and so on.  Is it also possible through php functions. Please let me know

Comment: I believe I have answered your original question. I'm quite sure what you ask is possible, but I don't know what it is you ask. You can create a new question if you wish. Adding to the same question is frowned upon here. Feel free to accept the answer if it have helped you.

Comment: Okay.. @Andreas,yes,  ofcourseYou helped me...Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!